# How do I rotate and scale edges in Edit Mode?

Tags: modeling, transforms

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49955/blender-tutorial-for-beginners-how-to-make-a-mushroom) mentions that it's possible to rotate and scale a selection while in *Edge Select* mode in the *Properties* panel. However, I can only find the option to transform the selection's median. There is no rotation or scale option in the panel.

[image]

How can I rotate and scale by entering a value in the panel in *Edit Mode*?

Comment: There are also keyboard shortcuts to do this, `G` (grab/translate), `R` (rotate) and `S` (scale).

Comment: And you can type in a value on the numpad after hitting `G`, `R`, or `S` to enter that value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Transform** panel in the **Properties** tab is only for moving mesh elements.
In Edit mode, you can transform the mesh using the **Properties** tab. In the top right of the **Properties** tab, you can see a **Transform** panel.

[image]

With mesh elements selected you can move them by **Transform tab**. Like you said, they only allow you to move them.

---

If you want to scale and rotate you use transform menu in the tool tab. Press <kbd>T</kbd> to open the tool tab. On the top left you will see the **Transform** panel.

[image]

You can click on this to interactively move mesh elements. After that, you can revise it in the **Operator** tab at the bottom of the tool tab.

[image]  [image]   [image]

---

The most popular method of doing these transforms is with the keyboard shortcuts. Using the keyboard shortcuts instead of the GUI is a lot faster and will speed up your workflow. With your cursor in the 3d view you can do:

<kbd>G</kbd>: grab, aka. move or translate

<kbd>R</kbd>: rotate

<kbd>S</kbd>: scale

You can also specify an axis for the transform by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> once you are in one of the transform modes. You can exclude an axis from the transform by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>axis</kbd>.
You can specify the exact amount of transform by pressing the numbers once in transform mode.

Some examples:

<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> move 2 units along x axis

<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> rotate 90 degrees along the x and y axis

<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> scale by a factor of 2