# How to move a mesh without disturbing origin point

Tags: mesh, transforms

Whenever I try to move a mesh in any direction, the origin point also moves along with it, I am working on a project which is based on particle emanations, so I have to make the origin point glued to its original location.

Can any one help me out for this?

Comment: Switch to _Edit Mode_ and try to move the mesh instead of moving the object in _Object Mode_.

Comment: @poor Add that as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest way is switching to *Edit Mode* and **moving the mesh** instead of moving the object in *Object Mode*, thus the **origin stays in place**:

[image]

1. *Select* the object
2. Toggle to *Edit Mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to make sure all vertices/edges/faces are selected
4. Move the mesh via *Grab/Move* <kbd>G</kbd> **or** simply use the *3d Manipulators*

In order to get **precise control** about moving the mesh, also see:

- [Is there a shortcut or hotkey that I could use to access the Transform panel of the properties shelf in the 3D viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15571/is-there-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-that-i-could-use-to-access-the-transform-panel-of/15572#15572)
- [How do I rotate and scale edges in Edit Mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/how-do-i-rotate-and-scale-edges-in-edit-mode/7101#7101)
- [Constrain to any 2 axes during transform?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/constrain-to-any-2-axes-during-transform/7492#7492)

Comment: can you help me out here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32486/how-to-get-animation-on-rendered-frames

Answer (score 3):

Before you move your mesh, make sure the 3D cursor is coincident with the origin, by selecting the object, and snapping (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) the 3D cursor, choosing the "3D cursor to selected" option. Then move the object where you want it, and set the origin using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and selecting the "origin to 3D cursor" option.

Comment: i am trying to mimic this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCEN0qQOsIA but i am struck at 2:30, where he grabs up the cube over z-axis, but the origin point stays where it was earlier, can you now figure out where am i going wrong ???

Comment: he hasn't used any of the shortcuts enlisted above but still he does it how ????

Comment: i've got the solution, he was in edit mode at that time

Comment: I think you meant shift+s?

Comment: I think you're right—fixed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

- move the Object to wherever you want. The origin will move too, don't worry.
- put the 3d Cursor where you would like the Origin of that Object to be.
- then *Object-> Transform -> Origin to 3d Cursor* (or pick it from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)